# mySQL - use an outer query value as a column name for a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have one table that holds exam questions; another table that holds exam answers.

I want to develop a query that will list the exam questions, and the most common answer for each one.

The relevant parts of the questions table is like this:

```
name    question_text 
ex1_qs1 1.    What is furry and has four legs? 
ex1_qs2 2.    What is hairless and has two legs?
```

The relevant parts of the responses table is like this:

```
session_id  ex1_qs1 ex1_qs2 
123456789   cat man 
112233445   dog woman
111222333   dog woman
```

I know I can get the list of questions like this:

```
Select name, question_text 
From questions
Order By LENGTH(name), name
```

And the most common response for each question like this:

```
SELECT ex1_qs1
FROM responses
GROUP BY ex1_qs1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I'm not seeing how to put it all together as a subquery, since the column name that I need for the subquery is a value from the main query. I can't hardcode this as a bunch of UNIONs either.

What do I use below instead of the hardcoded "ex1_qs1" (since I need to use the value of the "name" field in the outer query)? Or is there another approach needed?

```
Select name, question_text, (SELECT ex1_qs1 FROM responses GROUP BY ex1_qs1 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1) as most_common_response 
From questions
Order By LENGTH(name), name
```

Comment: Are you in a position to change the structure of the `responses` table? It should be normalized such that you have columns `session_id, question_name, response` where `question_name` is a foreign key to the `questions` table, rather than a column per question. That would make this a lot easier to manage...

Comment: Hi Michael, I agree, but no, unfortunately I am not in a position to change it. The website uses a component for these exams.

Comment: Not sure you'll be able to in this setup. Perhaps creating a new summary table and having automated code that updates it at regular intervals would work.